# How to remove the observer on the path in Firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, chat

I have a list of chat room ids and i want to add snapshot listener on each chat room id. This is being added by looping all the chat room ids and adding observer on each as below:

```
private func addObserverOnEachChatRoom(data: [ChatListInfo]) {
    for chatInfo in data {
        if let roomId = chatInfo.chatRoomId,
            !roomId.isEmpty {
            self.addObserverOnChatRoomToFetchLastMessage(roomId: roomId)
        }
    }
}

//add observer on a chat room id
func addObserverOnChatRoomToFetchLastMessage(roomId: String, completion: @escaping (_ lastMessage: Message) -> Void, failure: (_ error: Error) -> Void) {
    self.messageListener = self.chatsFirestoreRef.document(roomId).collection("messages").order(by: "time").addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            //FIXME: Handle the error here
            return
        }
        if let document = snapshot?.documents.last?.data() {
            do {
                let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: document, options: .prettyPrinted)
                let message = try JSONDecoder().decode(Message.self, from: jsonData)
                completion(message)
            } catch (let error) {
                DILog.print(items: error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I remove a listener on a particular chat id? In firebase, we could traverse path to the node and remove observer on that but in Firestore how can I reference a particular collection if the observers are added in a loop on multiple items.

Comment: if else condition :D

Answer (score 1):

When you add an observer the API returns a handle that you can use to unsubscribe. From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener):

> ```
> let listener = db.collection("cities").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
>     // ...
> }
>
> // ...
>
> // Stop listening to changes
> listener.remove()
> ```

Since you have multiple observers, one per chat room id, you'll want to keep a dictionary of these listener by chat room id.

```
var listenersByChatRoomId: [String, String] = [:];

...

listenersByChatRoomId[roomId] = self.messageListener;
```

And then you can unsubscribe from updates on a specific room with:

```
listenersByChatRoomId[roomId].remove()
listenersByChatRoomId[roomId] = nil
```

Comment: Is this the only way to remove the listener? I wonder why this is not like in firebase we could remove observer by traversing the path to the node with the id and directly remove the observer.

Comment: Removing an observer from Firestore requires that you have the handle. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Query